# Haskell List with tuples which can be extended - like a Dictionary

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary

I am a beginner in Haskell and trying to learn it, so please excuse my obliviousness.

I am currently trying to implement a Telephone book, which is a List of tuples `[(Name, Number)]` (Both are `String`s).

```
type TelephoneBook = [(String),(String)] (?)
```

However, I have no clue how I can extend this list by another tuple. 
For example: [("Fred", "47/273")] and now I want to add another tuple.

I was trying to understand how the module dictionary works to see how I can extend this List and I stumbled upon "data" and "type".

An idea I had was to create a several types of this `TelephonBook`:

```
let a = TelephoneBook ("Fred","42/2321")
```

but that is just a simple idea... I am kinda lost on how to extend this list by another tuple, taking into account that once something is defined it can't be altered (or can it).

(Please don't give the solution to the Problem but simply an idea on how to start or what I should Research further)

Comment: You need more basics.  Try going through the beginning of a tutorial or book, e.g. Learn You A Haskell For Great Good, or Real World Haskell (both are free online)

Comment: Just a minor detail: it is *tuple* not *touple*...

Comment: Yeah I am currently doing this aswell but due to having to learn for several tests I kinda have to rush it and do a lot of tasks etc whilst just reading as we have to know haskel wuite in depth but did it only for 2 weeks in university ^^ rest is up to us to learn :P thanks for the help though

Comment: And trust me I am spending every minute I have in learning to become better... yesterday I was trying to solve problems until 10 pm :) Sometimes you just need a little nudge though. (I looked for something like this in learn yourself a haskell but didn't find anything / missed it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you're asking to extend a list:
i have to disappoint you. That's not possible in Haskell. You can construct a new one. Out of one Element and another List.

the list type in Haskell is defined similar to:

```
--   1     2       3 4
data [a] = a : [a] | []
-- 1: if you encounter the type [a]
-- 3: it is either
-- 2: an element `e` and a list `l` forming the new list `e:l`
-- 4: or an empty List `[]`
-- so the types of the constructors are:
-- (:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
-- []  :: [a]
```

So having a new element and a list you can construct a new one, using `(:)`!

```
type Entry = (String, String)
type Book = [Entry]

addEntry :: Entry -> Book -> Book
addEntry e b = e : b -- this works, because book is just a list

-- without type aliases: (this is the same, but maybe slightly less nice to read)
addEntry' :: (String, String) -> [(String, String)] -> [(String, String)]
addEntry' e b = e : b

-- or even simpler:
addEntry'' = (:)
```

The `type` keyword in Haskell has to be understood as a type alias, so it's just another name for something, the representation in Haskell is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The `(:)` operator prepends elements to lists. For example:

```
> ("John", "555-1212") : [("Fred", "42/2321")]
[("John","555-1212"),("Fred","42/2321")]
```

Comment: In the end it's always the easiest solution -_- thanks Daniel